# parse data in parquet without changing datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I am using Python to randomly generate test data and trying to parse data from a Parquet file without changing the data types.

However, when I convert the data to a Parquet file, all of the data types get changed. I need to retain the DATE data type and would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your problem using the following code.

I create a DataFrame with a datetime column. I save the dataframe to parquet and read it again.

```
import pandas

date_list = pandas.to_datetime(["14.06.2023","15.06.2023","17.06.2023"])
value_list = [1,3,8] 

df = pandas.DataFrame() 
df["Date"] = date_list 
df["values"] = value_list 
df.to_parquet("test_file.gzip",compression="gzip")
    
df2 = pandas.read_parquet("test_file.gzip")
```

The type of the columns stayed the same for me.

Type of the original dataframe

```
df["Date"]
Out[1]: 
0   2023-06-14
1   2023-06-15
2   2023-06-17
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Type of the loaded dataframe

```
df2["Date"]
Out[2]: 
0   2023-06-14
1   2023-06-15
2   2023-06-17
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Could you elaborate your question more, or add a code snippet?

Comment: the code u gave is working fine for datetime but i m looking for date thanks a lot